# Generate Markers from Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array of markers coded into a web page and I use them to generate markers for a google map in the form of

```
generateMarkers([['Location', lat, long], ['Location2', lat2, long2],['Location3', lat3, long]3]);
```

So now am attempting to retrieve marker positions from a database so I attempted to use the code below to do so

```
getmkrs(
  <?php
        $db_con = mysql_connect("localhost",'root','');
        mysql_select_db("db_name",$db_con);
        $query_db = "Select * From table_name";
        $result = mysql_query($query_db, $db_con);
        $joiner = '';
    ?>

var_markers = [<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):?>
<?= $joiner ?>
[<?= $addslashes($row['Row1']) ?>, <?= $row['Row2'] ?>, <?= $row['Row3'] ?>                     ]       
<?$joiner = ','?>
<?php endwhile; ?>];
```

);

But Ultimately the page turns up blank, not even the map shows up. I am trying to replicate the above array which I coded into the web page. So my question is how can I efficient generate markers using data from a databse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the love of god, don't cobble together JSON by hand interspersed in Javascript code. Create a sane data structure in PHP and encode it using `json_encode`:

```
<?php
    $db_con = mysql_connect("localhost", 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db("db_name", $db_con);
    $query_db = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query_db, $db_con);

    $markers = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $markers[] = array($row['Row1'], $row['Row2'], $row['Row3']);
    }
?>
<script>
    var markers = <?php echo json_encode($markers); ?>;
    generateMarkers(markers);
</script>
```